# convert 2D array with .map in a "columns to rows" fashion

Tags: swift

I have a nested array that holds a bunch of "rows" and those hold a bunch of datapoints. To convert them to "columns" I use 2 loops that go over the nested array and reverse the dimensionality (put correct terminology here). (part 1)

At the moment I am trying to reduce the number of loops as much as possible and use .map .filter and .reduce.

Is it possible to get a complete reversal with map?
I already got it to one loop and one map. (part 2)

I got stuck because you can't really put the `$0` in there twice.

(this is very playground friendly)

Part 1:

```
var rowsArray : [[Int]] = []

for iA in 0..<10 {

    rowsArray.append([])

    for iB in 0..<2 {

        rowsArray[iA].append(iA * iB)

    }
}

var columnsArray : [[Int]] = []

for _ in 0..<rowsArray[0].count {
    columnsArray.append([])
}


for iA in 0..<rowsArray.count {

    let currentRow = rowsArray[iA]

    for iB in 0..<currentRow.count {

        let currentInt = currentRow[iB]

        columnsArray[iB].append(currentInt)

    }
}
```

Part 2:

```
var secondColumnsArray : [[Int]] = []

for iA in 0..<rowsArray[0].count {

    let column = rowsArray.map { $0[iA] }
    secondColumnsArray.append(column)

}

print(rowsArray)
print(columnsArray)
print(secondColumnsArray)
```

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your Part 2, personally; that's exactly how I would have done it. :) Remember, `map` is a loop, so you are looping exactly the same number of times no matter how you express this - any combination of `map` and `for..in` will be identical.

Comment: nothing wrong with it, just being curious.

Comment: But nothing to be gained by doing it any other way, I assure you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

Swift2:

```
let columnsArray = rowsArray[0].indices.map { col in
    rowsArray.indices.map { row in
        rowsArray[row][col]
    }
}
```

Swift1.2:

```
let columnsArray = map(indices(rowsArray[0])) { col in
    map(indices(rowsArray)) { row in
        rowsArray[row][col]
    }
}
```

Comment: that last edit is cool. Didn't quit get what was happing with the `(0..<rowsArray[0].count).map` part.

Comment: `indices` returns `Range<Self.Index>` whereas `0..<array.count` returns `Range<Int>`. While you are working with `Array`, it has no difference. But we should use `Index` instead of `Int` when we are working with arbitrary `CollectionType`, and subscript with them.

Comment: Got it! Kudos on the swift 2 and 1.2 answer btw